# REGEX combining regex strings then finding everything but the matches

Tags: regex

I have two regex strings:

1. `[^'"0-9+\-%*\/<>\!=&|]`
2. `(['"])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1`

The first one finds anything but the listed characters.
The second one finds anything between quotes, including the quotes.

I want to merge these so that I find anything that matches these characters or group of characters between quotes, excludes the matches it found, and returns everything else. For example in the following phrases, I want it to return only the bolded characters.

> ***Hello world*** "This is a test" 
> "Another test" 5 x 4 
> 'And this has an escaped quote don\'t in it ' ***Blue Boy***
>
> "This has a single quote ' but doesn't end the quote as it started
> with double quotes" 
> ***hello*** 
> 28 + 2 / 10 * 3 ***abc***
>
> " Lorem ipsum dolor\" sit 'amet' "

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way would be to replace second match with a blank string, then use the first regex to see if it matches your characters.

Comment: Thanks, that would work. However, I guess I made a mistake in the question and have updated the question. I am looking for any characters besides those in the first regex.

Comment: Can the quoted part be in the middle of the string? And what should happen when it finds one the excluded characters, should it fail?

Comment: `(?:(['"])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1|\d+(?:\s*[*\/+x-]\s*\d+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?=\S)[^'"0-9+\-%*\/<>\!=&|]+`, see https://regex101.com/r/awZe72/1

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a PCRE pattern like

```
(?:(['"])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1|\d+(?:\s*[*\/+x-]\s*\d+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?=\S)[^'"0-9+\-%*\/<>\!=&|]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/awZe72/1)

**Details**

- `(?:(['"])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1|\d+(?:\s*[*\/+x-]\s*\d+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)` - either a substring between `"` or `'` chars or 1+ digits followed with 0 or more occurrences of `/`, `+`, `-`, `*` or `x` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and then 1+ digits, the match is discarded and the next match is searched for from the location of the failure
- `|`
- `(?=\S)` - next char must be a non-whitespace char
- `[^'"0-9+\-%*\/<>\!=&|]+` - 1 or more chars other than the chars specified inside the negated character class.